# Fetching data from excel sheet placed sharepoint and updating data in the same excel sheet using VBA

Tags: vba, sharepoint

I have gone through the topics -  Import Sharepoint 2010 list data from Excel table using VBA discussed in this site. Could someone please help me with the below URL as to where can I find them? I have been given the Data Management mini project to fetch and insert the data in excel sheet placed sharepoint but not sure where acn I find sharepoint link.

I have one more requirement of inserting data to the excelsheet placed in sharepoint. Kindly help me with this requirement.

Thank you in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should get you going.

```
Sub UpdateSpecificCells()

'If nobody has the file checked out
If Workbooks.CanCheckOut("http://excel-pc:43231/Shared Documents/ExcelList.xlsb") = True Then
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Open the file on the SharePoint server
Workbooks.Open Filename:="http://excel-pc:43231/Shared Documents/ExcelList.xlsb", UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksNever


ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 7).Value = 100
ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 7).Value = 200
ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 7).Value = 300


'Close the workbook
Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsb").Save
Workbooks("ExcelList.xlsb").Close

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi There, Thank you for your response. Could you please help me with the sharepoint link as to which sharepoint link shall I use? I have to create a small tool which fetches data and insert data to an excel sheet placed in sharepoint. But, I am not sure which sharepoint link shall I use?